# Grouping events by shared timeframes

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here's a good one:  Say you have a table of call logs with start and stop columns as datetime - something loosely like this:

```
callID, start, end, caller, callee
1, 12/9/13 7:01 am, 12/9/13 7:15 am,  555-1212, 222-1616
2, 12/9/13 7:04 am, 12/9/13 7:06 am,  555-1213, 222-1516
3, 12/9/13 7:04 am, 12/9/13 7:10 am,  555-1222, 222-1646
4, 12/9/13 7:07 am, 12/9/13 7:31 am,  555-1312, 222-1674
5, 12/9/13 7:08 am, 12/9/13 7:10 am,  555-1417, 222-1655
```

How could I find the maximum number of concurrent calls for the day (what was the highest number of calls that overlap start and end times) - and the callIDs for that set?

Trying to figure out the best strategy for comparing multiple durations.  thanks!

Comment: Please tell me that `start` and `end` are `datetime` columns?

Comment: trying to wrap my mind around generating a temporary concurrence table, something like concurrenceID, callID but the concept of having to compare the start of a row to the start and end of other rows, and the end to the start and end of other rows has my head spinning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do it. Seems a little complex (I don't like having to do the time join twice) but should be relatively easy to follow:

```
declare @t table (callID int not null,start datetime not null,[end] datetime not null,[caller] char(8) not null,callee char(8) not null)
insert into @t(callID, start, [end], [caller], callee) values
(1, '2013-09-12T07:01:00', '2013-09-12T07:15:00',  '555-1212', '222-1616'),
(2, '2013-09-12T07:04:00', '2013-09-12T07:06:00',  '555-1213', '222-1516'),
(3, '2013-09-12T07:04:00', '2013-09-12T07:10:00',  '555-1222', '222-1646'),
(4, '2013-09-12T07:07:00', '2013-09-12T07:31:00',  '555-1312', '222-1674'),
(5, '2013-09-12T07:08:00', '2013-09-12T07:10:00',  '555-1417', '222-1655')

;With Starts as (
    select Distinct start from @t
), Groups as (
    select s.start,COUNT(*) Cnt
    from Starts s inner join @t t on t.start <= s.start and t.[end] > s.start
    group by s.start
), Ordered as (
    select start,Cnt,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Cnt desc) as rnk
    from Groups
), CallGroups as (
    select start,Cnt,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start) as CallGroup
    from Ordered
    where rnk = 1
)
select CallGroup,t.*,cg.start
from CallGroups cg
    inner join
        @t t
            on
                t.start <= cg.start and t.[end] > cg.start
```

`@t` is just your sample data. The `Starts` CTE finds all call start times - logically, the maximum number of concurrent calls was reached at *some* point when one or more calls was just starting.

`Groups` then finds all calls that overlap each start time. `Ordered` and `CallGroups` then finds the time(s) when a maximum was reached (because there could be more than one maximum in the data set and I decided to find all such maxima), and assigns each maxima a separate `CallGroup` value.

Finally, for the maxima, we reselect all calls that were active for each maximum:

```
CallGroup            callID      start                   end                     caller   callee   start
-------------------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------- -------- -----------------------
1                    1           2013-09-12 07:01:00.000 2013-09-12 07:15:00.000 555-1212 222-1616 2013-09-12 07:08:00.000
1                    3           2013-09-12 07:04:00.000 2013-09-12 07:10:00.000 555-1222 222-1646 2013-09-12 07:08:00.000
1                    4           2013-09-12 07:07:00.000 2013-09-12 07:31:00.000 555-1312 222-1674 2013-09-12 07:08:00.000
1                    5           2013-09-12 07:08:00.000 2013-09-12 07:10:00.000 555-1417 222-1655 2013-09-12 07:08:00.000
```

So, the maximum (only one) from your sample data occurred at 07:08, and was for four calls (if you want the count included, just add `cg.Cnt` into the final query). If there was another time at which four calls were reached, we would have 8 output rows, with `CallGroup` 2 for the second set of four.

---

Realised I can eliminate one CTE. Instead of:

```
, Ordered as (
    select start,Cnt,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Cnt desc) as rnk
    from Groups
), CallGroups as (
    select start,Cnt,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start) as CallGroup
    from Ordered
    where rnk = 1
)
select CallGroup,t.*,cg.start
from CallGroups cg
    inner join
        @t t
            on
                t.start <= cg.start and t.[end] > cg.start
```

We can just have:

```
, CallGroups as (
    select start,Cnt,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Cnt desc) as rnk,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cnt ORDER BY start) as CallGroup
    from Groups
)
select CallGroup,t.*,cg.start
from CallGroups cg
    inner join
        @t t
            on
                t.start <= cg.start and t.[end] > cg.start
where cg.rnk = 1
```

I'd been misthinking that we needed the result of the `RANK()` before we could assign continuous `CallGroup` values but that's not the case.